# Solving capacitor voltage "drops"?

Tags: capacitor

I'm having some problems solving the voltages across the capacitors in the following circuit:

[image: Circuit]

Because it is a parallel circuit, we know the voltage across C3 must be 6V.

But how can you figure out the voltage across C1 and C2? Does C1 store all the energy and leave C2 with no voltage? Or is it proportional?

I tried solving it in [CircuitLab](http://circuitlab.com), and it calculates 6V across C1 and 0V across C2...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The charge on C1 and C2 must be equal by conservation of charge because the node between them is isolated.  The voltage of C1 and C2 must sum to 6V.  Use q=CV and solve for the voltages.

---

Reworked by RM:

**Take 3:**

The same current flows in C1 & C2.
As charge is, by definition, proportional to current (Q = I x t) then
 the charge on C1 and C2 must be equal.

But, also by definition Charge = capacitance x Voltage (Q = C x V).
 Or, rearranging, V = Q/C.
 So, for equal charges in each, capacitor voltage will be inversely proportional to capacitance.

The voltage of C1 and C2 must sum to 6V.  Use q=CV and solve for the voltages.

**Wrap**

---

**Take 2:**

The relationship between charge Q, voltage V and capacitance C is given by the expression
  Q = C x V.
 Rearranging, V = Q/C.

Charge Q is defined as the summation of current with time ie Q = i x t
 As an identical current must flow C1 and C2, they both experience the same current x time profile so their charges are equal.

But from above, Vcap = Q/C.
 ie for equal charges, cap voltages will be inversely proportional to capacitor sizes.

So, in this example, the voltages on C1 & C2 will be inversely proportional to capacitor sizes so VC1 = 2 x VC2.
 By inspection, VC2 = 2, VC1 = 4.

Comment: Ah, so 6(V1) = 12(V2). So C1 voltage is 4V and C2 voltage is 2V. Got it!

Comment: @mr_schlomo - a tip with simulation, try setting "start supply voltages at 0V" (or an equivalent, e.g step voltage from 0 to 6V) and it should simulate correctly (at least it does in LTSpice)

Comment: Why must they be equal?

Comment: This answer is poorer than @stevenh 's and should not be the accepted answer. No offense madrivereric, but steven shows much more effort.

Comment: @abdullah - thanks! But OP accepted the answer before I had posted mine, and he hasn't been here since. Personally I also think he needs to explain his first sentence. Note that the accepted answer often doesn't change anymore, even [if the total of votes is negative](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/247/2064).

Comment: @abdullahkahraman - "Pooer" is (often) in the mind of the beholder. Just a little addition to madrivereric's answer would make it a very good one indeed and easier to follow that Steven's one. S's answer is OK but beginner's eyes are going to glaze over at the j.omegas. || Charge = summation i.t / Same current MUST flow through C1 & C2 so charges must be equal and then q= CV gives you the rest. elegant.

Comment: @stevenvh - "Shouldn't" is such a strong word :-). Could have, Seemed useful this way. He could have done in it in a few words. eg "Because the same current flows in C1 & C2 and as charge is proportional to current then ...". It's certainly not that his answer was "no good" - just , as ever, could be better. You and I both have more than enough points. "Pour encouragement les autres" (not in the way that is usually used :-) ) seems in order.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon well now, with the last edit, steven's answer is better, more practical, more easy.. Also, it includes the needed (well, for some people) details. Brilliant :)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon ow, sorry didn't see the edit you've made to this answer..

Comment: You should explain how you apply the conservation of charge

Comment: @abdullahkahraman - 1.It's good that community effort helped Steven improve his answer :-) 2.I still disagree - his answer now says "Just do this (but the details of why are below)" and that is what  madrivereric's answer now also says BUT the "details below" are simpler in Eric's answer. This does not make Steven's answer bad or wrong - just more complex. The idea of balanced charge WAS Eric's original contribution and is brilliant (IMHO) as a way of clarifying the problem. I tjhink it is better than Steven's method for a beginner - but, again, this does NOT make Steven's answer wrong or bad.

Comment: @Russell - I did explain that I approached it as a simple voltage divider (basic electronics), which uses the impedance for a capacitor (required electronics). Apart from the limit, the rest is junior high school algebra. It looks complicated, but I showed every step, and everyone who has a basic knowledge of electronics should be able to fathom this.

Comment: @stevenvh - I'll say again (3rd time now) - your answer is not bad or wrong, just more complex. And fwiw the impedance of the capacitor is not required electronics when looking at it from the V=Q/C and "equal Iin x t leads to equal charge in" concepts. (or, the impedance is arrived at in a simpler manner. The two formulae above allow the problem to be solved with no omega, no Pi, no rotating vector metaphors etc. It's brilliant and obvious. (And no, I didn't propose using it on this occasion.)

Answer (score 10):

"The charge on C1 and C2 must be equal" doesn't explain it. Why must they be equal?

Just think of it as a voltage divider, but while for resistors \$  V_{R2} = \dfrac{R2}{R1 + R2} V1 \$, for capacitors: \$  V_{C2} = \dfrac{C1}{C1 + C2} V1 \$. Notice the different indices in the numerator.

---

**Proof**

> WARNING. Ugly equations ahead. Don't worry if they look too complicated; all you need in practice is the equation above.

.
.
.
.
.
.
.

\$ V_{C2} = \dfrac{Z_{C2}}{Z_{C1} + Z_{C2}}V1 = \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{j\omega C2}}{\dfrac{1}{j\omega C1} + \dfrac{1}{j\omega C2}} V1 = \dfrac{\dfrac{C1}{j\omega C1 C2}}{\dfrac{C2}{j\omega C1 C2} + \dfrac{C1}{j\omega C1 C2}} V1 = \dfrac{C1}{C1 + C2} V1 \$

The last step is only allowed for \$\omega \ne 0\$. For DC we have to take the limit:

\$  V_{C2} = \displaystyle \lim_{\omega \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{C1}{j\omega C1 C2}}{\dfrac{C2}{j\omega C1 C2} + \dfrac{C1}{j\omega C1 C2}} V1 = \dfrac{C1}{C1 + C2} V1 \$

You don't need to do this derivation each time, just remember that it's the inverse of a resistor divider.

Comment: +1 but I'd like more an explanation involving charge conservation (should come from the fact that in the central plates there is the same charge as well). I think that it would be a stronger explanation

Comment: @clabacchio - Russell commented to the other answer *"S's answer is OK but beginner's eyes are going to glaze over at the j.omegas."* It might look scary to a beginner who just wants to know what voltage on each cap.

Comment: @stevenvh: well, the trick is to use Laplace's `s` :)

Comment: @clabacchio - That's right, the equations *look* simpler, until I have to explain the transform :-/

Comment: @clabacchio - sorry for the trouble you took, but I rolled back. I could have kept the subscripts. But you can't just eliminate \$j\omega C1 C2\$ if \$\omega\$ is zero. That's the DC from the question. You can't eliminate \$\infty/\infty\$. That's where the limit comes in. I checked with the guys at math.stackexchange and they agreed.

Comment: @stevenvh: I disagree, because that ratio cancels, since both members are equal, so they go to infinite in the same way. I'm pretty sure you can cancel, and indeed the result is the same. Also, if you do \$1=\frac{1+x }{x } = 1\$, for any value of x

Comment: @clabacchio - your example isn't correct, but I know what you mean. Canceling division by zero allows you to [prove that all numbers are equal to all other numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy). That's a case for the limit, but since the infinities are all the same they cancel. But only as a limit.

Comment: @stevenvh: not all infinities are the same, for instance \$\lim_{x->\infty}\frac{x}{x^2}=0\$. But those values are *exactly* the same, hence I think they can cancel: like \$\lim_{x->\infty}\frac{x}{x}=\frac{x}{x}=1\$. It may be *formally* wrong, but nobody will complain here anyway :)

Comment: @clabacchio - I know not all are the same. The infinity of the count of the real numbers is different from the infinity of the count of the natural numbers, for instance. All Cantor's fault (though he has a nice and simple proof of it).

Comment: I'd like to dive more in this subject, but I think that for the sake of electronics it's a fair assumption to cancel those factors, because it works for any value of omega

Comment: @clabacchio - [OT] Ehi clab', come to think of it. Got an e-mail this morning from someone at CircuitLab to tell me they have connection dots in the schematics now. I had just discovered it a few minutes before. That guy had seen my schematic with the hand-placed china ink dots ;-).

Comment: @stevenvh: which one??? But great idea, it's worth +1 Olin point

Comment: @clabacchio - [this one](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/33612/2064)